# Batch to add line to output

Tags: file, search, batch-file, cmd, lines

I am in need of some help again with my batch program.  While I've managed to figure out how to work on my converter (thanks to some members here) I now need to search through a file and add specific numbers to the output of the program.

Here is a part of what I am reading from

```
<unitNumber>7200</unitNumber>
<unitNumber>7419</unitNumber>
<unitNumber>724190</unitNumber>
<unitNumber>172419</unitNumber>
```

This "unitNumber" could be in excess of 50 lines, but I need the program to only find the 4 numbers, not the 6.

I would also need to put the numbers it finds, to an output such as this:
(after it finds the tag from the unit's weight, pulled from an earlier part of the code)

```
<unitWeight>17.34</unitWeight> (unitNumber would go here)
<unitWeight>17.34</unitWeight> (unitNumber would go here)
<unitWeight>17.34</unitWeight> (unitNumber would go here)
```

Here is what I have thus far in my code..seems to search everything, but fails to find the specific data within the file..

```
For /F %%G IN (distance1.txt) Do (
Find "7200" "distance1.txt"
Find "7419" "distance1.txt"
If %%G LEQ 7200 goto Nonefind
If %%G GEQ 7419 goto Nonefind 
)

:Nonefind
Echo None Found!
pause
```

If I could get some help I'd greatly Appreciate it.
Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Are you expecting your `find` commands to do something other than print what it found to the screen?  I think if you add the line `echo %%G` to your loop, you might be surprised at what it prints.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.You need to extract every 4-digit number between xml tags and output to another file with which lines look like `<unitWeight>17.34</unitWeight> 7200` ?

Comment: you need to find a number, you know already.

Comment: npocmaka, that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=><" %%a in ('findstr ">[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]<" distance1.txt') do echo ^<unitWeight^>17.34^</unitWeight^> %%a
```

Comment: this is getting close.

I also have the find and create another txt doc called distance2.  So I have the program find 17-7 in the <loadWeightUSTons> fields.  Again this pulls a pretty big amount of tags.

Find "17" "distance2.txt" && "16" "distance2.txt" and so forth and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
For /F "tokens=2delims=><" %%G IN (distance1.txt) Do (
 If %%G GEQ 7200 IF %%G LEQ 7419 Echo ^<unitWeight^>17.34^</unitWeight^> %%G
)
```

Comment: Magoo, I tired your code, it don't work.  Instead of having a reoccurring 17.34 the program will need to find all numbers from 17 to 5.  Then input that number were the example was given. Then, next to that number output the 'unitNumber' next to it.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about "17 to 5", no indication of where the "17 to 5" comes from and your example output repeats "17.34". Maybe I need new batteries in the crystal ball?

Comment: not sure about new batteries and the crystal ball.  the 17 to 5 comes from another source. I am using the 'Find' command to create a txt document that has numbers ranging from 0-999999.  I was able to extract and output 17-5.  Now I need to add what unitNumber corisponds to 17-5 on the screen.

Comment: If the `17.34` is substituted by some other variable, then replace `17.34` by `%var%` where `var` is the variable name.

Comment: ok I do understand that, thanks.  How would I get %var% from the find?

Comment: I've absolutely no idea whatsoever. you've not intimated where the data is arriving from. "17.34" appears from nowhere and it appears you wish to replace it with some other number, but you haven't shown sample data of the source or specified the method of extraction. I can only conclude that the value in question is the unit's weight which you state has been "pulled from an earlier part of the code" - beyond that, you've not elucidated.

Comment: OK I will do my best to to try and explain..

Find "loadWeightUSTons" "C:\AlphaProgram\FileName.xml > distance1.txt
Find "unitNumber" "C:\AlphaProgram\FileName.xml > distance2.txt